# "the word" vs "the words"

Tags: singular-vs-plural

A dictionary entry for *plume* says this:

> As he spoke, **the word** was accompanied by a white plume of breath.

I think people normally speaks many **words**, so does the sentence above mean only **one word** was spoken? Or does it mean **the Word (of God)**?

Comment: It does read like only one word was spoken. Nice Oxford comma, too.

Comment: In this context, it seems like *the word* is referring to just one word being spoken.

Comment: It would sure help if you told us where you found this sentence. Without more context, the meaning is ambiguous.

Comment: @J.R. I found it in dictionary when looking up plume, so there is no context I could provide.

Comment: @CYC - Um, that _is_ context. You could have told us that in your question. When you leave that information out, some of us imagine some preacher on a street corner in a Dickens novel, some of us imagine a cornered criminal in a Grisham novel, and some of us imagine CYC as a budding writer asking for some help. All of us could benefit from knowing that it's nothing more than a sentence coming from a dictionary entry, under the word _plume_.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

We don't have any specific record of what he said, so it's entirely possible for the man of this quote to have said only one word — "no", for example, or "leave", or any number of other single-word utterances. Since the source uses the singular, it's only reasonable to assume it did so on purpose. So "the word" here just refers to some particular single word that he's assumed to have said, which would normally* have been stated already.

<sub>**It's also possible for a complete story to mention only that he said something without saying what it was at first; for example, "He turned around and said something sharply. As he spoke, the word was accompanied by a white plume of breath." And then it could continue for some time before revealing what that word was.*</sub>

Answer (score -1):

I'm not a Christian, but this sounds like an extract from the Bible (Especially since you mentioned *'God'*). I think it is correct and the usage of the *'word'* is most apt. As you mentioned, people refer to it as the *"**Word of God**"*, not because he used a single word, but the word indicates a message and not an actual word, per se. 
 [Check out this link](http://dailyverses.net/the-word). Here are 29 verses from the Holy book in which *'word'* is used at least 26 times and not *'words'*.

Comment: This passage does not sound like anything I've ever read in the Old or New Testaments in any of a number of translations, and I would be surprised if it was in the Apocrypha, either. Its style is a more verbose, evocative, scene-setting one generally appropriate for fiction.